# Python SQLite: Taking user input for an order of fruit, finding price from database, and multiplying with quantity for a receipt

Tags: python, sqlite, user-input, multiplication

I have a python program using sqlite and I'm trying to create a function to take user input for a simple order of fruit. I have 2 user inputs; a string and an int and have a float in my database. What i want to do is take the name and quantity input from the user, then multiply the quantity with the price float in the database and write the resulting float to text file along with the name and quantity, to simulate a email style receipt.

main file:

```py
     #user inputs
     purchaseName = str(input("Enter Name:"))
     purchaseQuantity = int(input("Enter Quantity:"))
     purchaseConfirm = str(input("Confirm your order with y/n:"))
```

second file with sqlite database:

```py
#entries to be inserted into database
productEntries = [(1, "Strawberries", 1.50, 123),
                  (2, "Blueberries", 1.30, 178),
                  (3, "Raspberries", 1.40, 145),
                  (4, "Gooseberries", 2.30, 121),
                  (5, "Blackberries", 1.70, 90)]

#statement to insert values into database
cursor.executemany("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO products (productID, productName, productPrice, productQuantity) VALUES "
                   "(?, ?, ?, ?);", productEntries)

#create table to store the data
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
                productID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                productName TEXT NOT NULL,
                productPrice REAL,
                productQuantity INTEGER
                );""")

#attempt to perform calculation on the price and quantity values
cursor.execute("SELECT productPrice * productQuantity FROM products WHERE productName=?", purchaseName)

#variable to be sent back to main file to be written to txt file
purchasePrice = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: You need to create the table before you insert into it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning the total value of the product in inventory, because you're multiplying by `productQuantity`. To get the total price of the purchase you must multiply by `purchaseQuantity`.

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT productPrice * ? 
    FROM products WHERE 
    productName=?""", (purchaseQuantity, purchaseName))
```